# Is it possible to make the eclipse workspace path change per computer

Tags: windows, eclipse, usb-drive

I'm trying to make my eclipse 'portable' (on a USB, workspace and program included) but, because some random guy said that drive names don't count and that the drive has to be designated as a letter given by each computer, I have to change at least 7 paths every time I use a new computer. 
I'm sure it's possible but I'm just too new at programming to make a 'mod' that can do that. 
My computer is a WINDOWS 7, and I'm using Eclipse with ADT.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [Eclipse's Path Variables](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cpathvars.htm) instead of absolute path in your Eclipse settings. For example, you can reference something relative to Eclipse home folder like so:

```
${ECLIPSE_HOME}\..\someFolder
```

instead of doing

```
Y:\someFolder
```

That will work assuming someFolder and Eclipse folders are in the root of your USB stick.
This should work for most of the paths you can set in your Eclipse/project preferences.